# JsDoc: mention a parameter in function description

Tags: jsdoc

i'm searching for a way to evidence (or link) a parameter in function description.

Here an example of function

```
/**
 * @function example
 * @description Compute difference between #arg1 and #arg2
 * @param {string} arg1 - First argument
 * @param {string} arg2 - Second argument
 **/
function example(arg1, arg2) {
    ...
}
```

How to mention " #arg1 " and " #arg2 " corrently?

Thanks in advance